# Basic WebSocket Server for Arduino Uno with W5500 Ethernet Shield

Tags: websocket, tcp, arduino, ethernet

I am fairly new to Arduino and I am trying to construct a generic WebSocket server which send simple ASCII values to a WebSocket client running via a python program connected to the Arduino via an Ethernet cable. I don't want to construct a full WebServer, rather I just want to use WebSocket, in order to avoid using HTTP.

I am unsure of what library I should use for a W5500 shield with an Arduino Uno. Nor can I find any comprehensive and simple examples of how a basic WebSocket Server is constructed in Arduino. Can any one provide some recommendations for appropriate libraries or with good pieces of example code?

Thanks in advance

Edit: Here is a basic attempt at a generic WebSocket server I have taken from the WebSockets_Generic.h library, just to outline what I would like to make:

```
#include <Ethernet2.h>
#include <WebSockets_Generic.h>

WebSocketsServer webSocket = WebSocketsServer(81);

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.

byte mac[] ={0xA8, 0x61, 0x0A, 0xAE, 0x69, 0x13};


// Select the IP address according to your local network
IPAddress ip(198, 162, 1, 177);

void webSocketEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length)
{
  switch (type)
  {
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
      //Serial.println( "[" + String(num) + "] Disconnected!");
      break;
    case WStype_CONNECTED:
      {
        Serial.println( "[" + String(num) + "] Connected!");
        //IPAddress ip = webSocket.remoteIP(num);
        //Serial.printf("[%u] Connected from %d.%d.%d.%d url: %s\n", num, ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3], payload);

        // send message to client
        webSocket.sendTXT(num, "Connected");
      }
      break;
    case WStype_TEXT:
      Serial.println( "[" + String(num) + "] get Text: " + String((char *) payload));

      // send message to client
      webSocket.sendTXT(num, "message here");

      // send data to all connected clients
       webSocket.broadcastTXT("message here");
      break;
    case WStype_BIN:
      Serial.println( "[" + String(num) + "] get binary length: " + String(length));
      
      //hexdump(payload, length);

      // send message to client
      // webSocket.sendBIN(num, payload, length);
      break;

      default:
        break;
  }
}

void setup()
{
  
  // Serial.begin(921600);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);

  // start the ethernet connection and the server:
  // Use DHCP dynamic IP and random mac
  uint16_t index = millis();
  // Use Static IP
  //Ethernet.begin(mac[index], clientIP);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  // server address, port and URL
  Serial.print("WebSockets Server @ IP address: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
 
  webSocket.begin();
  webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
}

void loop()
{
  webSocket.loop();
}
```

This does not compile and instead produces an error:

```
In file included from /home/user/Data/Code-pieces/Arduino-Flowmeter/test/test.ino:2:0:
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/WebSockets_Generic/src/:69:4: error: #error Version 2.x.x currently does not support Arduino with AVR since there is no support for std namespace of c++.
   #error Version 2.x.x currently does not support Arduino with AVR since there is no support for std namespace of c++.
    ^~~~~
/home/user/Arduino/libraries/WebSockets_Generic/src/WebSockets_Generic.h:70:4: error: #error Use Version 1.x.x. (ATmega branch)
   #error Use Version 1.x.x. (ATmega branch)
    ^~~~~
Multiple libraries were found for "Ethernet.h"
 Used: /home/user/Data/Code-pieces/arduino-1.8.14/libraries/Ethernet
 Not used: /home/user/Arduino/libraries/UIPEthernet
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.

WebSockets_Generic.h
This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: use the Arduino Ethernet library. what is wrong with the example?

Comment: I believe for a W5500, you need to use Ethernet2, like I have done in the example. In addition, I was under the impression that Ethernet does not include an explicit WebSocket protocol. When I try and compile the example, I obtain 'Error Compiling for Arduino Uno'. I believe this issue is with WebSockets_Generic.h

Comment: you believe wrong. Arduino Ethernet library supports W5500 since 2018. I didn't say Ethernet library supports WebSocket protocol. what error?

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for clarifying. Given that I do not want to set up a full WebServer, but just a WebSocket Server ( so without any of the HTTP communication or body text found in examples), is it really necessary to import the Ethernet library if it does not support WebSockets? I have added the error to the question.

Comment: and did you read the error message?

Comment: I also have a Arduino Sam Due R3 which could perhaps be used?

Comment: yes, so this error has to do with the fact I am using an Uno and WebSocket_Generic, with does not support AVR boards, so I should instead switch to a Due?